# Getting a vector when doing j by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very trivial question I can't find the answer for.
Using the mtcars data:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
mtcars<-as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[,.N, by=cyl]
mtcars

    cyl  N
1:   6  7
2:   4 11
3:   8 14
```

Can I directly get the N column as a vector, rather than as a column of a data.table?

Comment: like `mtcars[,.N, by=cyl]$N`?

Comment: You can use some of the base R methods of extracting a column `mtcars$N` or `mtcars[["N"]]`

Comment: Fyi, overwriting mtcars with a vector will be confusing to anyone who reads your code, since it is widely known/thought of as a data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[,.N, by=cyl]$N
mtcars
> [1]  7 11 14
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with base R, you could use:

```
sapply(unique(mtcars$cyl), function(x) sum(mtcars$cyl == x))
```

Comment: Or `table(mtcars$cyl)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Not if they want to maintain the order of groups. `table` will sort the result by `cyl`.